# how to perform special characters in elastic search with out appending \ or \\ for some special characters

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform elastic search on some code which contains a fairly amount of brackets. Is it possible to perform elastic search without appending \ or \ for some special characters, specifically [] and {}.

This is my code:

```
{
  "track_total_hits": true,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "query_string": {
                  "default_field":"GECORRIGEERDETOEVOEGING.formatted",
                  "query": "*{uer}*",
                  "analyze_wildcard": "true",
                  "default_operator": "AND"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "GECORRIGEERDETOEVOEGING"
  ],
  "size": 30,
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "ORDERNUMMER.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, Elastic search has few characters as reserved. They are,

> + - = && || > < ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /

In order to use those above characters in query, you need to escape them with ''.
Otherwise the query will produce errors or return incorrect results.
Check here for more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters